# Minizip compression how-to?

Tags: c++

My object is to compress a directory containing multiple files using Minizip to .zip archive.
I tried reading the documentation provided with Minizip along with the example, but I couldn't comprehend it.

Do I go about it by creating a zip file using zipOpen, and then just add files to the zip file using zipOpenNewFileInZip ? Something like this:

```
zipFile Compressed = zipOpen("Name", APPEND_STATUS_CREATEAFTER);
    int rt = zipOpenNewFileInZip(Compressed," What should I put here?" , &zfi, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, "", 0, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
```

Please help me understand what functions I need to do my objective.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370908/how-do-i-use-minizip-on-zlib

Comment: I have checked that example. I have a question: In the zipOpenNewFile, what should I put as the second parameter, the directory of the file I want to compress(add to the zip)?

Comment: As the linked question points out, and the name of the parameter to the function you can see in `zip.h` it is expecting a filename.

Comment: How does it guarantee that the file is there, meaning where should the file be placed for it to function correctly?