# Zlib and Minizip - How to add a new directory to a .zip file

Tags: c++, compression, zip, gzip, zlib

I have written an application to compress the contents of directory to a .zip file from C++, using [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) and [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html). Minizip is not well documented online but the file "zip.h" in the source code contains comments.

My application uses [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a list of all files (and subfolders) in the directory and then, as shown here [How do I use Minizip (on Zlib)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370908/how-do-i-use-minizip-on-zlib) creates a .zip file and opens new files within the .zip.

Then I read the source files with fopen and fread and write the contents to the newly created files in the .zip folder. This all works just fine if the directory to be compressed contains only files, and no subfolders, but I cannot decipher from the comments in the source code how I add a new folder to a .zip file and then write files to that folder.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, you don't need to create a new directory in the .zip file as a separate step. You can just pass the parameter "foldername\filename.ext" to the zipOpenNewFileInZip method and it will create the "foldername" directory for you then add a new file "filename.ext" to that directory.

Comment: what about an empty directory?