# Libzip zip_dir_add from manual not declared - C/C++

Tags: c++, c, libzip

I am quite new to C/C++ programming so please take that into account.

**Problem :**

When using the libzip library, some of the functions descibed on the [manual](http://www.nih.at/libzip/libzip.html) are said to be not declared in the scope when compiling.
  I read this [tutorial](http://slash.developpez.com/tutoriels/c/utilisation-libzip/) (in french sorry) which was written in 2011. It uses different function names (zip_dir_add is zip_add_dir etc..)

I think that might be due to the installation process. Or maybe I forgot to include some files..

**Here is what i have done so far :**

1)installing the libzip library using ubuntu packages like this :

```
sudo apt-get install libzip-dev libzip2
```

2) trying it on simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zip.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  struct zip *zip;
  int err(0);

  zip = zip_open("testzip.zip", ZIP_CREATE, &err);
  zip_dir_add(zip, "upld");
  zip_close(zip);

  return 0;
}
```

This returns : zip_dir_add was not declared in this scope

Any idea what could cause that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Well, did you try the other possibility for the function name?

Comment: I did, the file compiled but gave me an empty file as said above.

Comment: I don't see anywhere above where you said that.

Comment: Sorry i mixed underneath and above .. I meant in the comment of Tejas Pawar's answer. The problem is that when i read the documentation, there is no mention of zip_add_dir and when i use it, the archive created is empty.. (I am sorry i cannot upvote your answers, i dont have enough reputation yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has 2 parts, 1 why zip_dir_add is not being compiled, while the documentation suggests to use zip_dir_add as zip_add_dir is obsolete.  The answer is you might be referring to a different version of code and different version of documentation. To cross verify go to the include path of libZip and open zip.h and check zip_dir_add, which you would not find.

The second question is why, zip_add_dir is creating an empty archive file. The answer is when you add a directory to zip_add_dir, it does NOT automatically add all the files (underneath the directory) to the archive, you have to walk-through the directory and add individual files using zip_add.

Comment: You are right. As the version of libzip in the ubuntu packages does not correspond to the latest one. As i did not want to go throw the whole process of downloading and compiling the latest version of the library, i used the old one and it works fine finally. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You wrote it yourself: `zip_dir_add` actually should be `zip_add_dir` - or did I misunderstand?

<strike>EDIT: just had a quick look at the lib - indeed there exists `zip_dir_add`, but it's internal.  The externally declared wrapper is `zip_add_dir`.</strike>

EDIT2:
After another look, this time into <zip.h>.  There, `zip_add_dir` is marked as "deprecated" and `zip_dir_add` seems to be the way to go.

**I fear that your compiler tries to include zlib's `zip.h` and not yours.**

As you are on linux (obviously) I'd recommend to switch to some lib that is more widespread, like mentioned `zlib` (which includes `minizip`, and that is most likely what you need).  Read on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370908/how-do-i-use-minizip-on-zlib)!

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me the difference between internal and external ? Does internal tands for the functions used inside the library to make it work and external for the functions the end user should use ? In that case, where can i find a user documentation ?

Comment: @PVC: Yes that's right. As for documentation, you linked to it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know i put it but as said, there is no mention of zip_add_dir in the doc. I ll try to work it out with my other link. Thanks ! (I am sorry i cannot upvote your answers, i dont have enough reputation yet)

Comment: Look at my next edit above.  If you can't vote up, you still can make an answer "accepted" by clicking that nice hook so it turns green :)

Comment: Sorry, i have just seen your comment and edit. How can i check if it is the right zip.h that is called ? I know i could switch to another library but i was asked to work with this one. If there is no other possibility i ll change but i'd rather not. I checked and the version i am using is the 0.10 and not the 0.11. I tried to install the 0.11 from the tar provided on the libzip website but could not manage to do it... If i remove the packages there is always something missing and if i keep those, the 0.11 version is not used.I click the hook when i've an answer not if told to do smthg else :P

Comment: if your "special" zip library is in your source path, you should use `#include "relative_path_to/zip.h"` - using double-quotes makes the preprocessor search relative to the current file's location.  Using brackets makes the preprocessor scan the include-directories for the file.

Comment: On the other hand: if that libzip-dev you installed really is "your libzip", you should search for the right zip.h-file and give a path relative to your system's include directory within the brackets.  Using a good ide will most likely offer auto-completion for that.

Answer (score 1):

Function is `int zip_add_dir();`
Try it. It should work.

Comment: I did try it but it doesnot work. The zip archive is created but it is empty in the archive manager given with ubuntu..

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue. Unfortunately I cannot use zip_dir_add as it is introduced in the latest version and I cannot upgrade, hence has to use zip_add_dir. But end result is, it creates zip file but with no content in it. Any pointers?

Comment: If you want i can give you the code i use. It is fairly simple once you understand the different functions needed.