# decompress single file from archive in android

Tags: android, archive, compression

I have a big archive (zip in my case) with size ~100MB and with ~15000 files in it. I need to QUICKLY extract only one file form this archive.

I tried the next code:

```
final String zipPath = "archive.zip";
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(zipPath);

in = new ZipInputStream(fin);

for (ZipEntry entry = in.getNextEntry(); entry != null; entry = in.getNextEntry()) {
    if(entry.equals("file.name")){
    //unzip this entry
    break;
}
}
```

It works but too SLOW.

Is it some another possibility to find necessary file in archive? For example, on linux it extremally fast possible with command

```
unzip archive.zip myfile.name
```

In general, I need to find and decompress one file from some archive. It can be some another format... May be with another format it can be more easy.

Comment: Can you sort those filenames in one way or another?

Comment: Hi! I think, no. I have a ordinary zip archive. And I found that entries in archive reading in alphabet order, but if my file have name "zzz.file" there are a lot of time for find this file in archive.

Comment: If they are alphabetically sorted you can do a binary search (worst case complexity of O(log(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [libzip library](http://www.nih.at/libzip/).

Comment: Hi! Thank you for reply! But if I understood good libzip is a C library, can I use it on android?

Comment: Thank you for your tip! Really, I compiled libzip for android and now I have static library libzip.a This file I include to my project and I wrote `static { System.loadLibrary("zip"); }` in Activity. Project works! May be it is stupid question, but how I can now zip and unzip files? Where I should find a functions list? Please, explain me if it not too hard for you! Thank you!

Comment: Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440113/simple-way-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib