# Libzip example contains uninitialised values when checked with Valgrind

Tags: c++, zip, valgrind

I've been using libzip to handle zip files, and have based my code on the example found in rodrigo's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440113/simple-way-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib). Here's his code, for quick reference:

```cpp
#include <zip.h>

int main()
{
    //Open the ZIP archive
    int err = 0;
    zip *z = zip_open("foo.zip", 0, &err);

    //Search for the file of given name
    const char *name = "file.txt";
    struct zip_stat st;
    zip_stat_init(&st);
    zip_stat(z, name, 0, &st);

    //Alloc memory for its uncompressed contents
    char *contents = new char[st.size];

    //Read the compressed file
    zip_file *f = zip_fopen(z, "file.txt", 0);
    zip_fread(f, contents, st.size);
    zip_fclose(f);

    //And close the archive
    zip_close(z);
}
```

I traced the errors I subsequently got from Valgrind back to this code- it complains of an uninitialised value when opening the zipped "file.txt" using 'zip_fopen()`.

```
==29256== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==29256==    at 0x5B4B290: inflateReset2 (in /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
==29256==    by 0x5B4B37F: inflateInit2_ (in /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
==29256==    by 0x4E2EB8C: zip_fopen_index (in /usr/lib/libzip.so.1.0.0)
==29256==    by 0x400C32: main (main.cpp:24)
==29256==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==29256==    at 0x4C244E8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==29256==    by 0x5B4B35B: inflateInit2_ (in /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3.4)
==29256==    by 0x4E2EB8C: zip_fopen_index (in /usr/lib/libzip.so.1.0.0)
==29256==    by 0x400C32: main (main.cpp:24)
==29256==
==29256==
==29256== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29256==     in use at exit: 71 bytes in 1 blocks
==29256==   total heap usage: 26 allocs, 25 frees, 85,851 bytes allocated
==29256==
==29256== 71 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==29256==    at 0x4C24A72: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==29256==    by 0x400BEE: main (main.cpp:19)
```

I can't see where the uninitialised value is coming from in this code. Can anyone trace this, or does the fault lie with libzip itself? Should I switch to another zip library- for example, Minizip?

EDIT: The 71 bytes are the contents of file.txt which was read in- `delete[] contents;` tagged on the end will eliminate that.

(I'd have left a comment on the original answer to draw attention to the issue, but I do not have the requisite rep.)

Comment: The stack trace is slightly odd, you call zip_fopen but it says you're in zip_fopen_index. Can't see that there's any `#define` that defines either in terms of the other, so have to ask if it's the right stack trace.

Comment: I agree! I couldn't see anything like that in zip.h, it was another reason to ask here. Definitely the right trace though, I just ran it again to check. I'd be interested to see if anyone else can reproduce this.

Comment: You'd have to look through the source code for `inflateReset2()` to try to determine what variable is being used as a conditional before it was initialized. The source code holds the answer to the `zip_fopen_index()` question, too, I'm sure.

Comment: Added some more info to the answer below, the warning seems to be specific for the zlib version Ubuntu is using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made me look :)

Yes, it's an error inside zlib (used by libzip), since both the allocation and the use of the memory is inside `inflateInit2_` on the same call. Your code doesn't even have a chance to get to that memory.

I can repeat the problem using zlib 1.2.3, but it's not showing up anymore in 1.2.7. I didn't have the code for 1.2.3 available, but if you're looking at it, I'd check the initialization of `state` and how it's used inside `inflateReset2`.

Edit: Tracked down the problem, I downloaded Ubuntu's source package for zlib (1.2.3.4) and the offending line is;

```
if (state->wbits != windowBits && state->window != Z_NULL) {
```

`wbits` is not initialized previous to this, and will cause the warning. The odd thing is that neither the original zlib 1.2.3 or 1.2.4 have this problem, it seems to be unique for Ubuntu. 1.2.3 doesn't even have the function inflateReset2, and 1.2.4 has it right;

```
if (state->window != Z_NULL && state->wbits != (unsigned)windowBits) {
```

since `window` is previously initialized to Z_NULL, the uninitialized `wbits` read won't happen.