# How to create any customized Unix command?

Tags: c++, unix

I want to create one unix command, which will unzip the folder.
so, I am searching for the code, but I am not aware that how should I use such code to make  Unix command?

I have gone through various questions & answers but I don't get any perfect information.
So, can any one please suggest me any code (in C++ or C or any language to make exe) and to use it as a Unix command.

**NOTE:  I know command like 'unzip' is available in 'Mks toolkit' type of software but we can not use it, so I want to make command which can run through 'command prompt'**

Comment: Let's start by nailing down exactly what you're asking.  (A) Can you code?  (B) Do you know how to compile? ...  If the answer to either of these questions is "no", then you are in the wrong place.  If "yes" then please explain what is stopping you from running the program you created.

Comment: Why can you not use it? Write a script

Comment: Yes Paddy, I can code, i know how to compile.

Comment: Yes @Paddy,Its new to me, i have just joined this site. I can code in mostly any language, i know how to compile. The thing that I asked is **can you tell me how to create any command & can you tell me any code (in any language) to 'unzip' folder (without using 7zip or winzip exe) in the code???**. some may not able to understand the question so it doesn't mean that one can not code and there is no any rocket science to do code. I think everybody may agree with this.

Comment: So, are you asking for a specification of the ZIP and 7Z formats?  Your question is unclear, and rather odd.  You can't just rock in here and ask how to write a complex program from scratch, with no idea how to even start.  If you can code and compile, I don't really see what's stopping you from looking up the format specification(s) and writing a program using your language of preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a command, you only need to create your executable and put its link in the `/usr/bin` folder.

Just compile your code and set a link to it's executable like this:

```
ln -s /path/to/your_executable /usr/bin/command_name
```

If there exists a command that you need to modify, you should set an alias to it. For example, you want `ls -1` to run whenever `ls` is used, then you only need to use the command:

```
alias ls=ls -1
```

or put the same command in the `.bashrc` file in your `home` directory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... can you tell me how to create any command & can you tell me any code (in any language) to 'unzip' folder (without using 7zip or winzip exe) in the code???

Comment: +1 @emab - this is really the only sane way to answer the question.  I almost wrote something to that effect yesterday, before realising that the OP is facing a challenge on a whole different level that we can't really deal with politely.

Comment: @BhushanJ that's a different question. If you want to write a code in c++ to unzip a file, you can use `libzip`. A complete example is provided in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440113/simple-way-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib

After you wrote the code, you can follow the steps in this answer to make it a unix command.