# unzipping a zip file with zlib/minizip: C/C++ Application

Tags: c++, c, zlib

My requirement is to unzip a zip file I am receiving from the server on Linux platform.
Now my `C/C++ code` should unzip the folder to receive the `json` files.

I did my research online and found I can use `zlib` library for this purpose, but zlib can not unzip a `.zip` file but it has in its `contrib` folder `minizip` which can be used for this purpose.

Referred: [Simple way to unzip a .zip file using zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440113/simple-way-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib)

I downloaded `zlib` source file:
`zlib source code, version 1.2.8, zipfile format (678K, MD5 checksum 126f8676442ffbd97884eb4d6f32afb4)` from http://www.zlib.net/

Now I go to `zlib-1.2.8\contrib\minizip` and try to compile `miniunz.c`

I try `make all` but getting below error:

```
[@DELL-BUILD03 minizip]$ make
cc -c -O -I../.. miniunz.c
cc -c -O -I../.. unzip.c
cc -c -O -I../.. ioapi.c
make: *** No rule to make target `../../libz.a', needed by `miniunz'.  Stop.
```

I tried manually placing a pre compiled `libz.a` in `zlib-1.2.8` folder.

But still the same error.
How do I proceed and `unzip` a sample `json.zip` folder?

Comment: If file exists and have adequate last modification date, it should work. I would recommend looking at https://code.google.com/p/miniz/ though, very nice single source file zip handler.

Comment: Build zlib two directories down using make, and it will leave a libz.a there.  Then do the make in the minizip directory.

Comment: @MarkAdler I did try placing pre compiled `libz.a` there but still same error. `zlib` make does not have any `target` or `build rule`

Comment: @keltar Tried `miniz` as well .. Again I am trying with it.. Using precompiled `example4` for my `json.zip` -----

Got below error
`[DELL-BUILD03 bin_linux]$ ./example4 json.zip a.txt
Input file size: 266631
tinfl_decompress_mem_to_callback() failed with status 0!
[DELL-BUILD03 bin_linux]$
`

Comment: @keltar Tried `miniz` .. It is able to decompress the file which it compressed itself.. The file received by server is giving above error.. The structure of received zip file is `json.zip-> it contains one file 320458_0902_00_05_502cf.json`

Comment: @GauravK function you referred to expects zlib stream as input, not zip structure. To read zip structure with miniz you should use `mz_zip_reader_init_file`, `mz_zip_reader_get_num_fieles`, etc..

Comment: @keltar That example I used successfully to `zip` and `unzip` a file say `a.json`. But for a `zipped file` (same structure which it successfully unzipped) which has been sent by a server, it is unable to unzip.So basically, it is able to `unzip` a file which has been `zipped` by itself

Comment: @GauravK you obviously doing it wrong. But that's a separate question. "It doesn't work" couldn't be helped without good specifics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved the error by running `make` first in `zlib-1.2.3` and then make in `minizip`