# How to make a .zip file using zlib

Tags: c, zip, zlib

I am reading through the document of zlib, and it is fairly detail. But I read upon this line:

> The output data will be in the **zlib** format, which is different from the gzip or **zip** formats
>   http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

It seems that zlib creates **zlib** format which is not the same as **zip** format as is discussed in this SO:

[How are zlib, gzip and zip related? What do they have in common and how are they different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762094/how-are-zlib-gzip-and-zip-related-what-are-is-common-and-how-are-they-differen)

Any body know whether it is possible to create zip format with zlib? and how?

Comment: It is mentioned [in zlib's FAQ](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Jongware mentioned, you can find an example in the [`contrib/minizip`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/tree/master/contrib/minizip) folder of the source code library.

OR !

You can simply use [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/index.html).

Possible duplicate: [Simple way to unzip a .zip file using zlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440113/simple-way-to-unzip-a-zip-file-using-zlib)